# How many Golden Enemies are there?

Tags: nier-automata

During my first playthrough, I encountered a Golden Small Stubby and a Golden Goliath Biped in the Sunken City area. In my second playthrough, I encountered a Golden Small Stubby and 2 Golden Goliath Bipeds in the City Ruins and a Golden Small Stubby and a Golden Tank in the desert area before the ruined desert city.

Are there any more of these Golden machines? If so, where are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This video has the location of all of the golden machine lifeforms:

In order, they are:

- Golden Goliath Biped (City Ruins)
- Golden Stubby (Flooded City)
- Golden Goliath Tank (Desert - Apartment Complex)

[This video also has the same three golden enemies](https://youtu.be/RrTcklVM2Ok).

As you progress, these enemies tell a story of revenge for killing their brethren, which I believe 9S comments on, questioning the motivation behind the concept of revenge, which the Pod describes as an old human behavior.

---

Unrelated to these golden enemies, there is also the Golden Bunny Statue in the Amusement Park, which is extremely useful for leveling up from around 60 to 99.

Comment: huh, so far all i've heard from 9S with the Golden Tank was him commenting that there might be more and when playing as 2B one of the Golden Machines in the Flooded City talked about revenge but that was after i killed one of them